# Computing score for a group based on row count and external logic

Tags: r

I am new to this site, and this is my first post.

I have the dataset where I would like to compute score for each group  using the previous row data, and apply a logic. I will provide a basic example, and I assume that will help.

Data:

```
S.no, Group, score1
1, GroupA, 1
2, GroupA, 0
3, GroupA, 1
4, GroupA, 1
5, GroupA, 1
```

Now I would like to compute the roll up `score1` for each row.
For row5, I want sum(`score1` from rows1 till 5)/5,i.e. 4/5
Similarly for row4, I want sum(`score1` from row1 till 4)/4, I.e. 3/4

I want to do the same for each rows for each group. I have demonstrated it for `GroupA` only for now.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Please include the code that you already have (whether it works completely or not).

Comment: Also please provide a sample of the data (e.g. using `dput`) and a sample of what you would like the output to look like - that will help other people provide a solution that works for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need `cumsum`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(score = cumsum(score1)/ row_number())
```

which gives

```
    Sno Group  score1 score
1     1 GroupA      1 1    
2     2 GroupA      0 0.5  
3     3 GroupA      1 0.667
4     4 GroupA      1 0.75 
5     5 GroupA      1 0.8
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Sno = 1:5, Group = c("GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupA", 
"GroupA", "GroupA"), score1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```